# Tezos Blockchain Time in SmartPy

Tags: smart-contracts, tezos-base, smartpy

I am new to Tezos Block chain and I am writing a smart-contract for crowdfunding using smartPy.
For this I need current date time of Tezos Block chain. So, can anyone help me out, how to find out this?
I had tried **sp.now** method but I am not able to implement it.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already discovered, the `sp.now` attribute should give you access to the current timestamp. You can see an example of this method in the "Mini-kitties" example that you can load in the [SmartPy.io IDE](https://smartpy.io/demo/) (`File` > `Load Template` > `Mini Kitties`). Specifically in the entry point `buy`, you'll find:

```
@sp.entryPoint
def buy(self, params):
    kitty = self.data.kitties[params.kittyId]
    sp.verify(sp.mutez(0) < kitty.price)
    sp.verify(kitty.price <= params.price)
    sp.verify(sp.amount == params.price)
    sp.send(kitty.owner, params.price)
    kitty.owner = sp.sender
    sp.if kitty.isNew:
        kitty.isNew = False
        kitty.auction = sp.now.addSeconds(self.newAuctionDuration)
    sp.verify(sp.now <= kitty.auction)
    sp.if sp.now <= kitty.auction:
        kitty.price = params.price + sp.mutez(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use 'sp.now', not 'sp.now()' or anything else. It's not a method, it's an expression that happens to do what you want.